# user logged in in one project is logged in in another project also, why? ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am having two websites which are completely separated but share a few things in common. The first website is a website for users contacting suppliers and the second website is an admin website for the suppliers.

These two websites sit as separate projects inside one solution.

Each website has its own user management with completely different databases to store the users.

However, when I login some user in one project and then run the second project this user appears as logged in the the second project (and vice versa).

How can I avoid this behaviour? Can anyone instruct me on this?

Comment: that doesn't sound right at all , there is something being shared there.  What you could do if you don't feel like looking for the root cause of the problem is setting roles on accounts and each site will use seperate roles

Comment: Yes, something must be shared there. I wouldn't want to make things more complicate by adding roles etc. because eventually this websites will be completely separated when on production. This behaviour just annoys me now, at design time. However, I feel that if I'll get to the bottom of this I will learn something about the authentication mechanism of ASP.NET.

Comment: you test in your machine with localhost?try use a diffrent domain,it is maybe cookie.and do you use asp.net membership?